# How to change Visual Studio 2010 context menu size

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, configuration, contextmenu

I have enough vertical spaces up and down but Visual Studio context menu restricts context menu and made itself scrollable.

Is there a configuration option to change the behavior of how context menu is displayed?

**Goal:** I'd like to display all items without having to scroll.

[image: Scrollable Context Menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I was able to reproduce this was by setting my resolution to a lower value to where the ContextMenu actually does not fit on the screen. In your screenshot though it does look as if the ContextMenu is opening up towards the top and hitting the top edge of your screen, which is that case the scrolling is normal behavior.

There is no way that I know of to change or customize the behavior of the ContextMenu within Visual Studio.

**Edit**

[Accoring to this topic](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpide/thread/7aaeec6b-d239-40cf-ae3a-341112cead6c), it is a known issue scheduled to be fixed in a future release.

Comment: Do you think it'd be feasible to write an extension to change the behavior myself?

Comment: http://www.helixoft.com/blog/archives/16 shows you how to modify the menu for Code View, but I am not sure if there's a way to do it for right clicking projects. What you are experiencing is just the default behavior of almost any context menu control.

Comment: Thanks, David.  I have voted on Microsoft *Connect* site for this annoyance to go away. If i were to create a Visual Studio extension to get around this, I'd post the link here.

Answer (score 1):

no, there isn't

Comment: Are you also able to reproduce the same behavior? I wonder if this isn't getting in your way of coding...